# After change of resolver to latest nightly I got strange message

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

What this does mean:

> The following packages specified by flags or options are not found:
>   persistent-sqlite

This is on the latest nightly nightly-2018-03-15 (GHC 8.4.1)

Note that the package I'm building doesn't depend on `persistent-sqlite`.

Comment: Which package are you building? If it is in Hackage and/or Stackage, what its version is? If not, can you post its .cabal file (or its `package.yaml`) and `stack.yaml`?

Comment: It's being worked upon: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3923

Comment: Thanks! I found another one - https://github.com/fpco/stackage/issues/3375